# RedisUtil shared connection pool false

Tags: java, tomcat, redis, atmosphere, jedis

I am using **Atmosphere** framework for my server side script on **tomcat** server.
I am also using **redis** server and using **jedis** library for java.

I am getting following log in tomcat console after which all the atmosphere connections gets close to server and server unable to communicate with client side:

```
10:59:51.443 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] INFO  o.a.samples.pubsub.EventsLogger - onDisconnect():   120.138.212.106:55163
11:01:52.502 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] INFO  o.a.plugin.redis.RedisBroadcaster - org.atmosphere.plugin.redis.RedisUtil shared connection pool false
11:01:52.504 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.a.util.AbstractBroadcasterProxy - Reconfiguring Broadcaster media1
11:01:52.505 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] INFO  o.a.samples.pubsub.EventsLogger - onSuspend(): 120.138.212.106:55166
11:01:52.510 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] INFO  o.a.samples.pubsub.EventsLogger - onConnect(): WebSocketEvent{message='', type=CONNECT, webSocket=org.apache.catalina.websocket.WsOutbound@133e9fa}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

I am using following code for redis connection pool:

```
public class ServerStart implements ServletContextListener {

private static JedisPool pool;

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {        
        pool = new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(), "localhost", 6379);
}

public static Jedis getResourceFromPool() {
    Jedis jedis = pool.getResource();
    return jedis;
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {

}

}
```

I am using getResourceFromPool() method for getting redis connection.

Comment: How did you format you log output. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Atmosphere is using it's own Jedis Pool. To se it to true, add the following init-param

org.atmosphere.plugin.redis.RedisBroadcaster.sharedPool
  true

-- Jeanfrancois

Comment: I am new to redis server configuration. I have redis integrated on my ubuntu server. Where to add this line?

Comment: In Atmosphere's web.xml :-)